# testing controller statement undefined

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine

Hi I am new to testing with karma Jasmine. I am trying to test a function but it throws an error on a value that I haven't yet tested here is the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'statement' of undefined`
Here is the relevant code code in the describe block toggle options button I am getting the error (that is the only code I have added besides for injecting rootscope)

```
fdescribe('Online Statements', () => {
    const module = window.module;
    const inject = window.inject;

    beforeEach(module('wbbUiApp'));

    describe('Controller', () => {
        let scope;
        let controller;
        let injectibles;
        let bindings;

        const createController = userDetails => {
            inject(($componentController,
                $window,
                $filter,
                $rootScope) => {

                // The same `$inject` array values listed in `account-activity.controller.js`
                injectibles = {
                    $window,
                    $filter,
                    $rootScope
                };

                // The same bindings listed in `account-activity.component.js`
                bindings = {
                    accountDetails
                };

                controller = $componentController('onlineStatements', injectibles, bindings);
        });
     };
    describe('toggle options button', () => {
        //beforeEach(controller.statement = { showOptions: true })
        it('should set the scope value to the index', () => {
            const index = 1;
            const dateId = 1290488400000;
            controller.toggleOptions(index, dateId)
            expect(controller.activeRow).toEqual(index);
        })

    })

});
```

here is the code in the controller the Error is happening because of `this.statement.showOptions` I tried commenting it out and it works fine if its not in the controller. I have tried setting it in the construtor and the on init and just plain like this `statement: { showOptions: false }` like this `this.statement.showOptions = true;`

```
toggleOptions(index, currentDate) {
        // toggle the dropdown with all buttons if its new then showing options is always true
        if (currentDate === this.currentSelectedDate) {
            this.statement.showOptions = !this.statement.showOptions;
        } else {
            this.statement.showOptions = true;
        }

        this.activeRow = index;
        this.currentSelectedDate = currentDate;
    }
```

this might be something simple as I am just starting. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `beforeEach(controller.statement = { showOptions: true })` is not a valid way to do things. beforeEach accepts a function. This adds up to existing answer.

Comment: @estus I have tried many things including this one I can remove it. I have not excepted an answer yet since nothing has solved my problem. But out of curiosity why not I will upvote your answers if you explain yourself(even with a link).

Comment: I didn't feel it's quality answer. You said yourself the code needs a clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeEach(controller.statement = { showOptions: true })
```

is not a valid way to do things.

`beforeEach` accepts a function. It should be:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  controller.statement = { showOptions: true }
})
```

As another answer explains, `controller` variable isn't defined in the scope of the function it is used. It was defined in sibling `declare`. If both `describe` use controller instance with same local dependencies, the whole `inject(($componentController, ...)` should be moved to parent `describe`, where it can be joined with `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(module('wbbUiApp'));

beforeEach(inject(($componentController, ...));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've limited the variable scope of `controller` to the first describe(). In the second describe(), controller is going to be undefined because of that.

Comment: I am not using that variable but that is a good point I will clean up later I am trying many things now.